# Issue with trailingSwipeActions and rotation

Tags: swift, uitableview, swipe, ios11

I tried to implement new methods `trailingSwipeActionsForRowAt` and `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`to display row actions with icon...

Unfortunately I'm facing a weird bug when I rotate the device from landscape to portrait after a trailing swipe.

Here is my code

```
var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100

    view.addSubview(tableView)

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 15
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (action, view, handler) in
        print("Delete Action Tapped")

    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-info-50")


    let defaultAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { (action, view, handler) in
        print("default Action Tapped")
    }

    defaultAction.backgroundColor = .orange
    defaultAction.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-info-50")

    let swipeAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, defaultAction])
    swipeAction.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return swipeAction
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (action, view, handler) in
        print("Delete Action Tapped")
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .blue
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-info-50")

    let swipeAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    swipeAction.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return swipeAction
}
```

Landscape mode : 
[image]

Then switching to portrait mode:
[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205111/5052894).

You can reset the edit state of the cells so that the actions no longer appear using `setEditing(_:animated:)` inside `viewWillTransition(to:with:)`, which is called when the device is rotated.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
}
```

This only works when you call `setEditing(_:animated:)` **outside** the coordinator's `animate` method. Setting editing to false inside the `animation` block will have no effect.