# UITableViewCell actions in iOS 11 after device rotation are broken

Tags: ios, uitableview

I use standard UITableView and UITableViewRowAction classes. In iOS 11 after device rotation I have weird behaviour, here is the sample:

[image: Screen cast]

Basically, it breaks the table view. In real app with more complicated cells and table it even worse (overlapping cells, etc.) I already tried to call SetNeedsDisplay() on UITableView after rotation, doesn't help.

In iOS 10 actions looked slightly different and work perfectly.

Comment: try to reload tableView also in rotation method.

Comment: @sharadchauhan It works actually, just looks bad :)
Maybe any other solutions or at least ideas?

Comment: Try to deselect the row on viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator

Comment: @AntonioM Shown action is not a row selection.

Comment: Found a solution: I call UITableView.setEditing(false, false) in willRotate().

Comment: This is such a weird bug. Still happening in iOS 12. A pity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the comments mention this, but the clear winner is to cancel editing the cell on rotation:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

You can reset the edit state of the cells so that the actions no longer appear using `setEditing(_:animated:)` inside `viewWillTransition(to:with:)`, which is called when the device is rotated.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
}
```

This only works when you call `setEditing(_:animated:)` **outside** the coordinator's `animate` method. Setting editing to false inside the `animation` block will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom image in the as `UIContextualAction`, and I was still facing some issues just setting the `tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)` after the `super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)`, I had to embed it in perform without animations, and now it works fine :)

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer has, in my case, the problem that after rotation the table is not editable anymore. I fixed it with setting editing to true directly after setting it to false:

```
tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
```

I admit it's a kind of hacky, better solutions welcome ;)